# Swift synchronous function waiting for asynchronous functions to finish

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

In view controller, user can select images, then app will upload to server.

User can select multiples images at one, and can select multiple times.

Each image uploaded will returns an URL to download later.

There is a Submit button to save other info and URLs of uploaded images to server.

I want when user press Submit button, app will wait for all images uploaded (returns URL or throws an error).

I'm using await Taskgroup to upload images in parallel each time user select images.

Is there any way to wait for uploading tasks finish other than using sleep()?

**Update:**

My code to upload images:

```
let urls = try await upload(images: images, urls: urls)

func upload(images: [UIImage], urls: [String]) async throws -> [String] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: String.self, returning: [String].self) { group in
        for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
            group.addTask { [self] in
                guard let url = try? await upload(image: image, to: urls[index]) else {
                    return ""
                }
                return url
            }
        }
        
        var downloadURLs = [String]()
        
        for try await result in group {
            if result != "" {
                downloadURLs.append(result)
            }
        }
        
        return downloadURLs
    }
}
```

Uploading images and submitting data is 2 difference actions:

- User select images, after that app will upload them automatically.
- User can tap Submit button whenever they like, even when images being uploaded, app has to wait for uploading task finish before submit other data.

Comment: Don't wait. TaskGroup notifies when all tasks are completed.

Comment: It’s the beauty of Swift concurrency: you `await` the task group and just put the updating of the UI or model on the next line. No sleeping. No waiting. You just `await` the task group.

Comment: I added code and explained about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a dictionary `[URL: UIImage]` in your class to keep the state of the uploads (so add/remove when starting/finishing each) and enable your submit button only when that is empty? Do mind wrapping it into a class with a thread-safe implementation though.

EDIT: If the button can't be disabled, you could do something like below:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.viewModel.upload(url: URL(string: "https://google.com?id=\(UUID().uuidString)")!, image: UIImage())
                self.viewModel.upload(url: URL(string: "https://google.com?id=\(UUID().uuidString)")!, image: UIImage())
            }
            label: {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
            }
            
            Button {
                self.viewModel.submit()
            }
            label: {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var uploadRequests = [URL: UIImage]()
    var submitting = false
    
    let requestPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        self.cancellable = requestPublisher.filter { [weak self] _ in
            self?.submitting ?? false
        }.sink { [weak self] _ in
            self?.uploadToServer()
        }
    }
    
    func upload(url: URL, image: UIImage) {
        Task {
            print("Uploading image")
            
            self.uploadRequests[url] = image
            
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            
            self.uploadRequests[url] = nil
            
            print("Image uploaded")
            
            // If submit button was pressed meanwhile...
            if self.uploadRequests.count == 0 {
                self.requestPublisher.send(true)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func submit() {
        self.submitting = true
        
        guard self.uploadRequests.count == 0 else {
            print("Still ongoing requests")
            return
        }
        
        self.uploadToServer()
    }
    
    func uploadToServer() {
        Task { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            print("Uploading to server")
            
            self.submitting = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can upload, cancel upload, delete images now.

I can't use enable/disable way because user can select images many times, button can be enabled after some images uploaded.

And requirement is button must be always enabled

Comment: I see what you mean, editing my response to use a publisher to know when everything finished and trigger the upload, if the submit button was pressed in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you. It's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming your upload image function look like thís

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage) async -> URL { 
   // some logic
}
```

And you want to make many upload image task running in parallel and wait to all upload task to be done. So i think you can do something like

```
Task {
    submitButton.isEnable = false
    async let firstImage = uploadImage(image: image1)
    async let secondImage = uploadImage(image: image2)
    async let thirdImage = uploadImage(image: image3)
    let images = await [firstImage, secondImage, thirdImage]
    submitButton.isEnable = true
}
```

Comment: I can upload images in parallel. The problem is while images being uploaled, user can tap Submit button any time, and app have to wait for uploading tasks finish before submit.

Comment: @PhạmPhiPhúc So i think you can simply disable your submit button while start uploading and enable it when finish upload tasks

Comment: User can select images many times, button can be enabled unexpectedly after images selected in first time uploaded.